# Type Error when running function

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm trying to use FileInput to replace a line in a file, if a certain word is in the line. It basically appends to a file. It runs but gives me a TypeError,  I'm trying to figure out where the error is.

```
tagname = 'somestring'
def add_tags():
        for line in fileinput.FileInput('/tmp/hosttags.mk',inplace=1):
            if 'end_tags' in line:
                line = line.replace(""" ('end_tags',""", """('%s',
u'/%s',
 [('%s', u'%s tag', [])]),
 ('end_tags',
 u'testing/end_tags_start',
[('end_tag_id', u'end_tag_description', [])])]""") % ( tagname, tagname, tagname, tagname)
            print line.strip()
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tag_update.py", line 57, in <module>
    checkmk_srv_tag_update()
  File "./tag_update.py", line 54, in checkmk_srv_tag_update
    add_tags()
  File "./tag_update.py", line 45, in add_tags
    [('end_tag_id', u'end_tag_description', [])])]""") % ( tagname, tagname, tagname, tagname)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

end result of file being updated:

```
('house',
u'/house',
[('house', u'house tag', [])]),
('somestring',
u'/somestring', 
 [('somestring', u'somestring tag', [])]),
 ('end_tags',
 u'testing/end_tags_start',
[('end_tag_id', u'end_tag_description', [])])]
```

thanks

Comment: What happens if a line contains `end_tags` but not `('end_tags',`?

Comment: it matches the line

Answer (score 0):

you have wrongly put your bracket, you essentially doing

```
line = line.replace("xxx", "%s %s") % (tagname, tagname)
```

where its suppose to be

```
line = line.replace("xxx", "%s %s" % (tagname, tagname) )
```

lets say line = 'xxx', replace text match, it will works because it 1st replace become `"%s %s" % (tagname, tagname)`

when the replace text not match, it will fail because it become
original line `'xxx' % (tagname, tagname)`
 ,thus the error

The error can be fix also by changing the if part into

```
if " ('end_tags'," in line:
```

- fix the wrong bracket
- As Luke Woodward mention, your if checking is
  not matching the replace text portion, actually you can remove the if part, the code will work also as the replace will not happen when
  the replace text not matching
- instead of %, suggest to use string
  format 
  `line = line.replace("xxx", "{0} {0}".format(tagname)
  )`

Comment: All - thanks for your input. I need to add triple brackets to the matching text  to get this to work. It now works in a loop without error.

Answer (score 0):

All - thanks for your help.  I needed to add triple quotes to get this to work on the matching string.

final code:

```
    def srv_tags_update():

        tags_set = []
        for host,tags in ipa_hostgroups_dict.iteritems():
            tags_set += tags

        for host_tag in set(tags_set):
            for line in fileinput.FileInput('/tmp/hosttags.mk',inplace=1):
            #if 'end_tags' in line:
                if """('end_tags',"""  in line:
                    line = line.replace(""" ('end_tags',""", """('%s',
u'/%s',
 [('%s', u'%s tag', [])]),
 ('end_tags',
""")  % ( host_tag, host_tag, host_tag, host_tag  )
                print line.strip()
```